# Computation of the integral $\int_{0}^\infty \left( \frac{e^{\sqrt{2y}}-1}{\sqrt{2y}}\right)^2e^{-y}dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am currently struggling on the computation of the following integral:

$$I\triangleq \int_{0}^\infty \left( \frac{e^{\sqrt{2y}}-1}{\sqrt{2y}}\right)^2e^{-y}dy.$$

### My attempt

I have tried a the change of vartiable $y=u^2/2$ to have more "gaussian" integral forms, thus we have:

$$I = \int_0^\infty  \frac{(e^{u}-1)^2}{u}e^{-u^2/2}du.$$

But I don't know what to do with that, does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: write $\frac{1}{u}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ut}\,\mathrm{d}t$. Mathematica gives $$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\mathrm{erfi}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-2\mathrm{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+2{}_2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;2\right)-{}_2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you @KStarGamer ! With your hint (and Fubini theorem), I have $I = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-ut}(e^u-1)^2e^{-u^2/2}dudt$. By putting the $e^{-ut}$ into the gaussian exponential, I have some $e^{t^2}$ when I try to make a quadratic form appear, do you have any more hint please ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\left(e^u-1\right)^2}{u}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2 \left(2^n-1\right) }{(n+1)!}u^n$$
$$J_n=\int_0^\infty u^n \,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\,du=2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$$ gives
$$I = \int_0^\infty  \frac{(e^{u}-1)^2}{u}\,e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\,du=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \left(2^n-1\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{(n+1)!}$$
If $a_n$ is the summand
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\sim \frac{\left(2^{n+1}-1\right) (4 n-7)}{4 \left(2^n-1\right)
   n^{3/2}} \sim \frac 2{\sqrt n}$$

Using Mathematica

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{\frac{3 n+1}{2}} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{(n+1)!}=2 \, _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;2\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}  
   \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{\frac{
 n+1}{2}} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{(n+1)!}=\, _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{1}{2}\right)+\pi 
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Recombining
$$\large\color{blue}{I=2 \, _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;2\right)-\,
   _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{1}{2}\right)+}$$ $$\large\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{2}   \left(\text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-2
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}$$